# UITableView showing (null) for first row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am updating a UITableView with CoreData. On startup, the first row is showing as (null). If I scroll down/up, it loads though. It just doesnt show initially.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    // set text for each cell
    [cell.textLabel setText: [dataManager getProjectValueForKey: @"Title" atIndex: [indexPath row]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText: [[[dataManager getProjectValueForKey: @"pid" atIndex:[indexPath row]] stringByAppendingString: @": "] stringByAppendingString: [dataManager getProjectValueForKey: @"Sponsor" atIndex:[indexPath row]]]];

    return cell;
}
```

`dataManager` is what is talking to Core Data. I feel like it might be lagging behind or something on startup so the cell is trying to show the data before it is ready. But I don't know.

Comment: Does the proper text get loaded if you scroll that first cell off and back on screen? Also, you may want to look into NSFetchedResultsController for populating your UITableView with Core Data results. Its designed and highly optimized for that use case.

Comment: Yes, they do as mentioned in the op. I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's going on. I would set a breakpoint right there in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. First time around, step into `-getProjectValueForKey:atIndex:` and see why it's coming back as nil.

Comment: Without seeing the code for `dataManager` it is really hard to say, but possibly `dataManager` is one based instead of zero based?  I.e. when you set the data, do you start with 0 (as you should) or with 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a great "dataManager" already built into Core Data. It is called `NSFetchedResultsController`. You can always retrieve the correct data object for your table cell with

```
[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This is typically done inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and not in some other helper function. The fetched results controller will take care of everything that is necessary to retrieve the data that is needed in order to display it.

See also the numerous Core Data code examples from Apple for this common design pattern.